# Save Render Layers

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers

Whenever I render single layer all the other layers that were previously rendered are gone (see screenshot; only the sphere layer is rendered. The whole scene is visible in the backdrop).

**Is there a way to render single layer separately without having to render all the layers every single time and not losing the ones that were previously rendered?**

**Is the compositor intended to be used with multiple Render Layer nodes or saving each layer externaly via File Output node and then using the Image node to add the layer for compositing?** This is a two-step process instead of having only Render Layer nodes for each layer and then render (synchronize) just a single layer?[image: c]